# Font XCharter generates small caps in english, but not in dutch

Tags: fontspec, small-caps

The following MWE generates small caps correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\begin{document}
xxx\textsc{abcd}xxx
\end{document}
```

But when I change `english` to `dutch` I get a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/XCharter(1)/m/sc' undefined
```

and lower case characters are substituted.

Comment: What's the question? :-)

Comment: Quick fix: replace `\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia} \setmainlanguage{english}` with `\usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: Are you able to use `babel` rather than `polyglossia`?

Comment: Sure, with babel no problems, but I want to use the facilities of polyglossia, in which I suspect a bug - I'll go there to report that.